# ¿Cómo acceder a información de un array que descende de un modelo?

Tags: swift

Soy nuevo en desarrollo Swift y no he podido avanzar con esta parte de mi proyecto inicial.

Tengo este bloque array, que descende de un modelo 'Lost':

```
var personas: [Lost] {
    get {
        let persona1 = Lost(name: "Weda", age: "15", fromWhere: "Santiago", picture: weda_15_santiago.jpg")
        let persona2 = Lost(name: "Esmeweda", age: "18", fromWhere: "Santiago", picture: "esmeweda_18_santiago.jpg")
```

Cómo hago para acceder, por ejemplo, al array de los 'fromWhere' en otro archivo .swift dentro del proyecto? Trato de imprimir el dato del array en una label en otra vista.

Estoy intentando en esta parte del código en el `TableViewController` , pero no sé que va luego del =

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "LostCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LostTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.fromWhereLabel.text =
```

He intentado algo como:

```
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.fromWhereLabel.text = Lost.fromWhere[indexPath.row]
```

Pero no me ha resultado.

Gracias por su ayuda y sugerencia.

Comment: pon un punto de ruptura en el cellForRowAtIndex y puedes ir probando con un po a ver que va saliendo y te puedes hacer una idea de tu modelo de datos, por ejemplo po personas[indexPath.row], le añades .name o .age y puedes ir viendo que es lo que te va saliendo, creo que te puede ayudar a ver como obtener los diferentes valores de tu modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que has publicado, `fromWhere` no es ningún array. Es una propiedad de tipo `String` que está dentro de tu modelo `Lost`, que está incluido en el array `personas`.

Si `personas` está en el mismo fichero, o más bien en la misma clase que tu `func cellForRow...` lo que podrías hacer es:

`cell.fromWhereLabel.text = personas[indexPath.row].fromWhere`

Si no, pues necesitaría más código para saber como acceder a ese array `personas`. ¿En qué clase lo tienes declarado? ¿Cuál es la relación de esa clase con aquella en la que usas el método `cellForRow...`

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias jdev. Tal como dices en tu respuesta, efectivamente era una propiedad (String). Lo pude arreglar gracias a tu respuesta. Saludos.